# How to successfully host a React app on cPanel without nodejs support

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, cpanel

I am attempting to host a React app on cPanel within a subdomain. I have tried various methods, but I have one question: Is it possible to host a React app on cPanel if cPanel does not support Node or if Node is not installed? I am confused as none of the methods I've tried seem to work.